# converting an array of unixtime to mmddyy on python

Tags: python

I have an array of unixtime timestamps. How do I convert that using

```py
datetime.utcfromtimestamp().strftime("%Y-%M-%D %H:%M:%S")
```

? My array is saved under "time". How do I utilize that array in this conversion?

Comment: can you explain this part? "My array is saved under "time""

Comment: Please follow this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) to improve your chances of getting a reply.

Answer (score -1):

Assuming your times are of the format `datetime`, you can loop through the list and convert each one.
Here is a quick example:

```
import datetime 

time = []
for i in range(10): 
    time.append(datetime.datetime.now())

print(time) # output: [datetime.datetime(2020, 7, 8, 10, 7, 4, 314614), datetime.datetime(2020, 7, 8, 10, 7, 4, 314622)....

formattedTime = [] 
for t in time: 
    formattedTime.append(t.strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S'))


print(formattedTime) # output: ['2020-07-07/08/20 10:07:04', '2020-07-07/08/20 10:07:04', .... 

# the update to my answer: 
newTimes = [] 
for date_time_str in formattedTime: 
    newTimes.append(datetime.datetime.strptime(date_time_str, '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S'))

print(newTimes) # '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S' [datetime.datetime(2020, 7, 8, 18, 56, 47), datetime.datetime(2020, 7, 8, 18, 56, 47), datetime.datetime(2020, 7, 8, 18, 56, 47),...]
```

Let me know if you have more questions.

I am also attaching [this article](https://stackabuse.com/converting-strings-to-datetime-in-python/) for datetime which I found really helpful.

Here is the [example in repl](https://repl.it/repls/InfamousPoliticalExtraction#main.py)

Comment: The question states they are unix timestamps, and wants to know how to convert them to `datetime`.  Here you are “Assuming they are `datetime`” to begin with.

Comment: Sorry for the misunderstanding. I updated my answer.

Comment: @donkopotamus does this answer your question?